# Convert C# statements including NSubstitute code to VB.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, nsubstitute

While reading the NSubstitute tutorial i convert the samples written in C# to VB.net to understand the functionality, but I need your support for these (unrelated) statements, which I can't convert despite all the care taken:

1.

```
calculator().Received().Add(1, Arg.Is(Of Integer)(function(x) new[] {-2,-5,-10}.Contains(x)))
```

2.

Note: foo is a derived object from an interface with a void method called "SayHello"

```
foo.When(x >= x.SayHello("World")).Do(x => counter++);
```

3.

```
calculator().When(x >= x.Add(-2, -2)).Do(x => { throw new Exception(); });
```

Note: engine is a derived object from this interface:

```
public interface IEngine {
    event EventHandler Idling;
    event EventHandler<LowFuelWarningEventArgs> LowFuelWarning;
    event Action<int> RevvedAt;
}
```

4.

```
engine.Idling += (sender, args) => wasCalled = true;
```

5.

```
engine.Idling += Raise.EventWith(new object(), new EventArgs());
```

6.

```
engine.RevvedAt += rpm => revvedAt = rpm;
```

With your support I hope, I'm able to convert the remaining statements on my own.

Thank you in advance

Michael

Comment: Try putting your class in : http://converter.telerik.com/

Comment: Jeroen, thanks - i know this converter (and others) but they can't help me in all cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want to convert Lambda's and adding event handlers.

Lambda from c#

```
.Where(x => x.Foo = 1)
.Do(x => x.Bar())
```

translates into

```
.Where(function(x) x.Foo = 1)
.Do(sub(x) x.Bar())
```

In VB.Net you have to take into account if the Labda is actually performing a function or a sub and code it accordingly.

Adding events in c#

```
engine.Idling += MyEventHandler
```

in `VB.Net`

```
AddHandler engine.Idling, AddressOf MyEventHandler
```

`VB.Net` lets u add the event like this. Removing an event is done by the keyword `RemoveHandler`

Answer (score 1):

To add to Jeroen's answer, the general format for adding an event handler is:

```
AddHandler someObject.SomeEvent, SomeDelegate
```

You can use the `AddressOf` operator to create a delegate that refers to a named method but that is not the only way.  A Lambda also creates a delegate so this:

```
engine.Idling += (sender, args) => wasCalled = true;
```

becomes this:

```
AddHandler engine.Idling, Sub(sender, args) wasCalled = True
```

Also, this line is not actually adding an event handler:

```
engine.RevvedAt += rpm => revvedAt = rpm;
```

so AddHandler won't work.  I have never done it myself but I believe that you need to call `Delegate.Combine` for that:

```
engine.RevvedAt = [Delegate].Combine(engine.RevvedAt, Sub(rpm) revvedAt = rpm)
```

Comment: thanks. Together with Jeroens answer i was able to convert a few more statements. When i've converted all statements, i will mark an answer - in the other case, i ask you for one more support.