# How to raise an event from Fake instance of class derived from interface

Tags: .net, nsubstitute

Code under test

```vb
Public Class ObservableName
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Protected Sub RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName As String)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
    End Sub

    Private _Name as String
    Public Property Name As String
        Get
            Return _Name
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _Name = value
            Me.RaisePropertyChanged(NameOf(Me.Name))
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

Public Class ViewModel
    Public ReadOnly Property MyName As ObservableName
    Public Property CountOfChanges As Integer

    Public Sub New(name As ObservableName)
        Me.MyName = name
        AddHandler Me.MyName.PropertyChanged, AddressOf Me.MyName_PropertyChanged
    End Sub

    Protected Sub MyName_PropertyChanged(sender as Object, e As PropertyChangedEventArgs)
        If e.PropertyName.Equals(NameOf(Me.MyName.Name)) = True Then
            Me.CountOfChanges += 1
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Test using `NUnit` and `NSubstitute`.
Testing that changing Name(raise PropertyChanged event) will update CountOfChanges proerty

```vb
<Test>
Public Sub CountOfChanges_NameChanged_ShouldIncreaseByOne()
  Dim previuosCount As Integer = 0
  Dim nextCount As Integer = previuos + 1
  Dim fakename As ObservableName = Substitute.For(Of ObservableName)()
  Dim vm As New ViewModel(fakename)
  vm.CountOfChanges = previuosCount 

  AddHandler vm.MyName.PropertyChanged, Raise.Event(Of PropertyChangedEventHandler)(vm.MyName, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(NameOf(vm.MyName.Name)))

  Assert.AreEqual(nextCount, vm.CountOfChanges)
End Sub
```

Using above code will never raise a `PropertyChanged` event, but next test with straight using Of `INotifyPropertyChanged` passed will raise event successfully

```vb
<Test>
Public Sub PropertyChanged_RaiseEvent()
    Dim test As INotifyPropertyChanged = Substitute.For(Of INotifyPropertyChanged)()
    Dim isRaised As Boolean = False
    AddHandler test.PropertyChanged, Sub() isRaised = True

    AddHandler test.PropertyChanged, Raise.Event(Of PropertyChangedEventHandler)(test, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("test"))

    Assert.IsTrue(isRaised)
End Sub
```

Comment: You want to know how to raise the event or how to register the handler? I am not familiar with nsubstitute but I know that the syntax in VB.NET to register an event handler is: AddHandler test.Passed, AddressOf TheEventHandler. It seems to apply to nsubstitute as well, according to the answer in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23513811/convert-c-sharp-statements-including-nsubstitute-code-to-vb-net

Comment: Question about how to raise event. In `NSubstitute` raising event have same syntax as register an eventhandler [https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/raising-events/](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/raising-events/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really need to use NSubstitute here and use white-box testing?
If you set "pure technical interest" aside, it would be much simpler to just set the vm.myName.Name property in your test, and then assert that vm.CountOfChanges increased. This would be a "black box" approach, which does not depend on the details of internal implementation, and thus is more robust.
It still fully tests your functionality, just omits implementation details

To understand why it does not work as you expect, consider the following.
NSubstitute uses Castle.DynamicProxy to implement the substitutes - the mechanism that is used is inheritance. 
Event is a language feature that implemented by using a private delegate field with the same signature. The whole purpose of the event is to *encapsulate* a delegate.
Since the delegate field is private, you cannot access it in a derived class, and hence, cannot trigger the event.
To raise a base class event in an inherited class, the base class must have a vitual method to raise the event, which inherited class must override, see [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy3sefw3.aspx) for example, but there are plenty of good explanations of this on the web.

Comment: This approach I used right now. I think here a problem which I don't understand from documentation - _Events can only be directly invoked by their declaring class_

Comment: Hey, I've altered the answer to explain why it does not work as expected, let me know if additional detail is required. Cheers!